# Eclipse WindowBuilder Bug?

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

I am making a java application for patching mods and adding texture packs into Minecraft. I want it to use a online mod store accessed through the DJ Project JWebBrowser. I am using Eclipse WindowBuilder/hand coding to construct the UI. My problem is that WindowBuilder crashes with the following error

```
    Stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (125) and height (0) cannot be <= 0
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent.print(SWTNativeComponent.java:845)
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PeerPrintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.printAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.utils.SwingImageUtils$2.run(SwingImageUtils.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.utils.SwingImageUtils.runInDispatchThread(SwingImageUtils.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.utils.SwingImageUtils.createComponentShotAWT(SwingImageUtils.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.utils.SwingImageUtils.makeShotsHierarchy(SwingImageUtils.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.utils.SwingImageUtils.makeShotsHierarchy(SwingImageUtils.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.utils.SwingImageUtils.makeShotsHierarchy(SwingImageUtils.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.utils.SwingImageUtils.makeShotsHierarchy(SwingImageUtils.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.utils.SwingImageUtils.makeShotsHierarchy(SwingImageUtils.java:261)
```

The weird thing is that it works if I run it normally it works just fine. Here is the relevant source code:

```
setTitle("OpenMPatch");
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

        JPanel tabModStore = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Mod Store", null, tabModStore, "Mod Store");

        JWebBrowser modStore = new JWebBrowser();
        modStore.setStatusBarVisible(false);
        tabModStore.add(modStore);

        JPanel tabSettings = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Settings", null, tabSettings, "Settings");

        comboBoxTheme = new JComboBox();
        comboBoxTheme.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                setLAF(comboBoxTheme.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }
        });
        comboBoxTheme.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {
                "system", "java", "motif", "nimbus", "windows",
                "windowsclassic" }));
        try {
            comboBoxTheme.setSelectedItem(Config.ReadConfig().get("LAF"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            OpenMPatch.error(e);
        }

        JLabel lblTheme = new JLabel("Theme:");
        lblTheme.setLabelFor(comboBoxTheme);
        lblTheme.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        lblTheme.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);

        JButton btnSaveSettings = new JButton("Save Settings");
        btnSaveSettings.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                saveSettings();
            }
        });

        JButton btnRestoreDefualts = new JButton("Restore Defualts");
        btnRestoreDefualts.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    Config.restoreDefualts();
                    updateSettings();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    error(e);
                }
            }
        });
// Generated by WindowBuilder
        GroupLayout gl_tabSettings = new GroupLayout(tabSettings);
        gl_tabSettings
                .setHorizontalGroup(gl_tabSettings
                        .createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(
                                gl_tabSettings
                                        .createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addContainerGap()
                                        .addGroup(
                                                gl_tabSettings
                                                        .createParallelGroup(
                                                                Alignment.LEADING)
                                                        .addGroup(
                                                                gl_tabSettings
                                                                        .createSequentialGroup()
                                                                        .addComponent(
                                                                                lblTheme)
                                                                        .addPreferredGap(
                                                                                ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                        .addComponent(
                                                                                comboBoxTheme,
                                                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                        .addGroup(
                                                                gl_tabSettings
                                                                        .createSequentialGroup()
                                                                        .addComponent(
                                                                                btnSaveSettings)
                                                                        .addPreferredGap(
                                                                                ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                        .addComponent(
                                                                                btnRestoreDefualts)))
                                        .addContainerGap(365, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        gl_tabSettings
                .setVerticalGroup(gl_tabSettings
                        .createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(
                                gl_tabSettings
                                        .createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addContainerGap()
                                        .addGroup(
                                                gl_tabSettings
                                                        .createParallelGroup(
                                                                Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                        .addComponent(lblTheme)
                                                        .addComponent(
                                                                comboBoxTheme,
                                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addGap(18)
                                        .addGroup(
                                                gl_tabSettings
                                                        .createParallelGroup(
                                                                Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                        .addComponent(
                                                                btnSaveSettings)
                                                        .addComponent(
                                                                btnRestoreDefualts))
                                        .addContainerGap(274, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        tabSettings.setLayout(gl_tabSettings);

        JPanel statusBar = new JPanel();
        statusBar.setToolTipText("Status");
        getContentPane().add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                OpenMPatch.class.getResource("/alex/mik/openmpatch/icon.png")));

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);

        JMenuItem mntmOpenFile = new JMenuItem("Open File...");
        mntmOpenFile.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent) {

            }
        });
        mntmOpenFile.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O,
                InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        mnFile.add(mntmOpenFile);

        JMenuItem mntmOpenFolder = new JMenuItem("Open Folder...");
        mntmOpenFolder.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O,
                InputEvent.CTRL_MASK | InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK));
        mnFile.add(mntmOpenFolder);

        JSeparator fileSeparator1 = new JSeparator();
        mnFile.add(fileSeparator1);

        JMenuItem mntmQuit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        mntmQuit.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                close();
            }
        });
        mntmQuit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q,
                InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        mnFile.add(mntmQuit);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
```

And while I am here, the mntmQuit button does not do anything. I debugged it and it did not even run the mouseClicked event when I clicked on it.
I am using java 1.6, WindowBuilder 1.2.0.r37, Eclipse Indigo, and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Wow, that's some serious indenting!  Which line is line 845, the offending line?

Comment: Thats part of the [DJ project library](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/main/index.html) that I used

Comment: Ah, ok. What did you mean by "if I run it normally"?  What's normally?

Comment: Run as a java application in Eclipse, not preview in WindowBuilder.

Comment: I would not worry about it crashing in the WindowBuilder preview.  If it works fine when you run it from the command line then you're good. I recommend ditching the GUI creator and writing it all by hand. You'll probably be able to create what you want using `BorderLayout` and `BoxLayout` or the `Box` component.  Your code will be cleaner and more maintainable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can answer half your question - maybe with clarification I'll figure out the rest.

You need to attach an `ActionListener` to a `JMenuItem`, not a `MouseListener`.  See Oracle's tutorial [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for some very good examples.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, based on the exception, it looks like the chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent class caused the problem and WindowBuilder trapped the error for you. I assume it showed you this on the Design page (as it is designed to do) and did not actually "crash".

@Paul - WindowBuilder already generates very clear and very maintainable code, so there would be no reason to "ditch" it. It also extremely compatible with hand made mods so you can easily work back and forth in source or design mode, and WB will keep both in sync at all times.

Comment: Yeah, it showed it in the design page, but I'm not sure why windowbuilder would show an error and java wont.